# SSRS SQL closest future date to current date

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a table of securities (added spaces for better readability) with coupon payment dates (if it's a bond) and I need to make a table where for every client and security he owns, there is a column with only next coupon payment. If its a share, it will  be in the table but with no payment. 
So from column coupon payment date, I need to select only the next coupon payment date.

from this(let's call it table 'Coupons':
 
    ClientName I SecID I  SecType I   CouponPaymentdate
    Client1 I US00001 I Bond I 06/2017
    Client1 I US00001 I Bond I 06/2018
Client1 I US00001 I Bond I 06/2019
Client1 I US00001 I Bond I 06/2020
Client1 I US00001 I Bond I 06/2021

Client1 I US00002 I Bond I 03/2019
Client1 I US00002 I Bond I 03/2020
Client1 I US00002 I Bond I 03/2021

Client2 I US00003 I Share I -

Client3 I US00004 I Bond I 01/2017
Client3 I US00004 I Bond I 01/2018

desired result

ClientName I SecID I SecType I NextCouponPaymentdate
Client1 I US00001 I Bond I 06/2020
Client1 I US00002 I Bond I 03/2020
Client2 I US00003 I Share I -

for this column I tried this, but I need to break ClientName and SecID
   `(SELECT TOP 1 Coupons.CouponPaymentDate FROM Coupons as CPN
   WHERE CPN.CouponPaymentDate > GETDATE()
   ORDER BY CPN.CouponPaymentDate)`

Any advice? I use SSRS, so maybe even an expression for this would be helpful but I have no idea. Thank you (Sorry for formatting)

Comment: is your couponpaymentdate in that format? MM/YYYY ? also what if the current date is right between two couponpaymentdate  ?

Comment: format is dd.mm.yyyy but for simplification I used that one (but yes its mm/yyyy). If current date is right between two couponpaymentdates I need the closest future one. I dont care about past couponpaymentdates

Comment: quick question  desired result Client1 I US00001 I Bond I 06/2020 why not Client1 I US00001 I Bond I 06/2021 what is the logic behind your desired result

Comment: because 06/2020 is closer to current date than 06/2021

Answer (score 1):

edit: see Alan's solution. Seems to return same results with less code.

My approach for this is to create an additional column to calculate the difference between the payment date and use the row number function to determine the record closest to current day.

I created a temp table to insert the values you provided (I replaced "-" with null in the couponpaymentdate column for SecType = "Share") to test the result

```
CREATE TABLE #yourtable (
ClientName nvarchar(50), 
SecID nvarchar(50), 
SecType nvarchar(50), 
CouponPaymentDate datetime)

INSERT INTO #yourtable VALUES
('Client1', 'US00001', 'Bond' , '06/01/2017'),
('Client1', 'US00001', 'Bond' , '06/01/2018'),
('Client1', 'US00001', 'Bond' , '06/01/2019'),
('Client1', 'US00001', 'Bond' , '06/01/2020'),
('Client1', 'US00001', 'Bond' , '06/01/2021'),
('Client1', 'US00002', 'Bond' , '03/01/2019'),
('Client1', 'US00002', 'Bond' , '03/01/2020'),
('Client1', 'US00002', 'Bond' , '03/01/2021'),
('Client2', 'US00003', 'Share', null),      
('Client3', 'US00004', 'Bond' , '01/01/2017'),
('Client3', 'US00004', 'Bond' , '01/01/2018');
```

calculated difference in days in column aliased "duration_days" and include only future days/nulls

```
select 
ClientName,
SecID,
SecType,
CouponPaymentDate,
MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE(),CouponPaymentDate))) as duration_days
into #yourtable2
from #yourtable
WHERE (CouponPaymentDate > GETDATE() OR CouponPaymentDate is null)
group by ClientName,SecID,SecType,CouponPaymentDate
```

rn represents row number and since the rows are ordered by ascending duration_days, rn = 1 will be the date closest to current day. This will also provide you with the future date if the current day is right between two couponpaymentdates.

```
SELECT ClientName,SecID,SecType,CouponPaymentDate
FROM
(select 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by SecID order by duration_days, CouponPaymentDate desc) rn,
ClientName,
SecID,
SecType,
CouponPaymentDate,
duration_days
from #yourtable2
) table_alias
where rn = 1
```

**Replace #yourtable with Coupons

Answer (score 1):

The following should work. Just replace @t with your actual table name

```
SELECT 
        ClientName, SecID, SecType, NextCouponPaymentDate = CouponPaymentdate 
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                *
                , RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientName, SecID ORDER BY CouponPaymentdate)
            FROM @t WHERE CouponPaymentdate > getdate() OR SecType = 'Share'
            ) x 
    WHERE RowN =1
```

Ignoring the date format I used (YYYY-MM-DD) and the fact that I set the payments dates to hte first of each month, this gives you what you wanted

[image]